# Publish math formulas on Blogger

Tags: blogger

I can't use LaTeX and MathML.
 How do I publish math formulas in Blogger?
https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/00c22777378f9c594c71158fea8946f2495f2a28

Answer (score 1):

The link you provided is an SVG file. You can convert SVG files into popular graphic images such as `PNG` or `JPEG`, and attach them to Blogger.